# Let's help the Stack Overflow Blog post find the sponsor, or why do the Blog's posts keep missing disclosure headers?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, blog

Today, [yet another sponsored post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/04/24/instantly-verify-your-customers-online-with-open-banking-apis/?cb=1) appeared on the Stack Overflow blog. Such posts, apart from the "partner content" and "partnercontent" tags, are supposed to have a big header before the start of the content that one can find, for example, on [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/12/08/how-to-make-time-for-learning-in-tech/):

[image: "Sponsored by Pluralsight" header]

There was even a [commitment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/356700) from the company to properly mark those posts in three ways:

- a "sponsored post" subtitle in the sidebar (it's there);
- the "partner content" and "partnercontent" tags (both present);
- a big header that the content is sponsored (missing);

So, as the esteemed reader might've guessed, the question is: where did the "sponsored by Mastercard" header go? This is far from the only Blog post that's missing the disclosure header — it would be great if Stack Exchange stopped using the shady practice of trying to hide the fact that a post is sponsored as much as possible.

Comment: I want to see this fixed but I also am deeply pessimistic that anyone cares anymore...

Comment: @Makoto pretty sure nobody working on the blog cares at this point... But screaming in space has at least a therapeutic effect :)

Comment: Status-fixed: *Added default header "Sponsored by our sponsor" to all blogs*. Done. What's next?

Comment: I lost faith in the blog editors back when they consistently spewed out low-quality and blatantly incorrect posts. It has only gotten worse in terms of quality, so it isn't surprising that money takes precedence over ethical advertising practices (and post quality, but that's secondary in comparison). It shouldn't, though; at least with labeling.

Comment: @rene `rm -rf /blog`?

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine I don't think anyone would complain about that, to be honest.

Comment: I am altering the commitment. Pray I don't alter it any further.

Comment: Pity Steve McQueen's dead. He had experience in dealing with... Oh. Shit. Blobs. My bad.

Comment: *"[Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor)"*

Comment: The keyword being "adequately", @PeterMortensen :) I'd use the razor if I had any belief in the blog being anything but a marketing instrument...

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine "_`rm -rf /blog`_" here ya go: `#sidebar > .s-sidebarwidget__yellow .s-sidebarwidget--item:has(svg) { display: none !important; }`

Answer (score 12):

First, an apology for missing the sponsored disclaimer on the recent blog post. The community team has brought this to our attention and we are setting up a new system of checks that will involve a second layer of confirmation from our editorial and sales team to ensure all sponsored posts are properly marked. Additionally, the post used as an example has been fixed to include the banner it was missing. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Maybe do the same with Twitter posts? https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1677014979071950849?s=20